# Changing uri-design SEO

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, search-engine-indexing, url-rewriting

I think I need to redesign my uri-collections of my site.

Right now I am using the following structure by a mistake:

```
/fruits for the whole collection
/fruit/banana for an item in the collection
```

But I am changing this to:

```
/fruits
/fruits/banana
```

How will this affect my indexed pages of the search-engines? Should I create 303-redirects from the old collection structure to the new one? Or is it best to live with my mistake and not make the change?

Thanks,

James Ford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to change URLs structure, you can apply 301 redirections with .htaccess (if you use Apache Web Server) in order to indicate to Google you use new URLs. Google will replace old URLs by new ones in its index by itself.

If you want to see old URLs disappear more quickly, after new ones are indexed, you can ask remove them from index in Google Webmaster Tools (in menu: "Optimization" => "Remove URLs").

Otherwise, you can live without changing but If you want it's best to change, you can apply 301 redirections without many impacts for SEO. As you wish.